# Matlab related Sh file command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, matlab, sh

I'm trying to launch a program (ExploreDTI) which uses Matlab Runtime R2014a (8.3). I have a `MainExploreDTI` file (Executable (application/x-executable)) and a `run_MainExploreDTI.sh` sh-file.

In terminal, when I type `sudo ./run_MainExploreDTI.sh` it gives me the answer `command not found`.

Googling it, I've found the alternative command "sh run_MainExploreDTI.sh", now the error is

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is
.:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83//runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83//bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83//sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83//sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
run_MainExploreDTI.sh: 1: eval: ./MainExploreDTI: Permission denied
```

How can I solve it? Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

The `command not found` error means that the `run_MainExploreDTI.sh` is not executable. You have two choices:

1. Make it executable and then run it:

   ```
   chmod a+x run_MainExploreDTI.sh
   sudo ./run_MainExploreDTI.sh
   ```
2. Call it with `sh`:

   ```
   sudo sh run_MainExploreDTI.sh
   ```